# Variant title in dataLayer for GTM on Shopify

Tags: shopify, google-tag-manager, liquid, google-analytics-4, google-datalayer

Working on GTM and dataLayer building for the non plus store on Shopify.
My aim is to assign correct value for the `item_variant` in items array to get it in GA4. My dataLayer push in liquid looks as

```
/** DATALAYER: Product Page
        * Fire on all Product View pages. */
        {% if template contains 'product' %}  
            var ecommerce = {
                'items': [{
               'item_id'        : {{product.id | json}},  
               'item_variant'    : {{product.selected_or_first_available_variant.title | json}},             
               'item_name'      : {{product.title | json}},
               'price'           : {{product.price | divided_by: 100.0 | json}},
               'item_brand'      : {{product.vendor | json}},
               'item_category'   : {{product.type | json}},
               'item_list_name'  : {{collection.title | json}},
               'description'     : {{product.description | strip_newlines | strip_html | json}},
               'imageURL'        : 'https:{{product.featured_image.src|img_url:'grande'}}', 
               'productURL'      : '{{product.url}}'
                }]
            };               
            dataLayer.push({
                'pageType' : 'Product',
                'event'    : 'view_item',
                 ecommerce
                });
             {% endif %}
                      
            /** DATALAYER: Product Page
        * Fire on all Add to cart events. */
             {% if template contains 'product' %}  
            var ecommerce = {
               'items': [{
               'item_id'        : {{product.id | json}},                 
               'item_variant'    : {{product.selected_or_first_available_variant.title | json}},                
               'item_name'      : {{product.title | json}},
               'price'           : {{product.price | divided_by: 100.0 | json}},
               'item_brand'      : {{product.vendor | json}},
               'item_category'   : {{product.type | json}},
               'item_list_name'  : {{collection.title | json}},
               'description'     : {{product.description | strip_newlines | strip_html | json}},
               'imageURL'        : 'https:{{product.featured_image.src|img_url:'grande'}}', 
               'productURL'      : '{{product.url}}'
                }]
            };              
            $(__DL__.cartTriggers).click(function(){               
                dataLayer.push({                    
                    'event'    : 'add_to_cart',
                    ecommerce
                });                  
            });              
        {% endif %}
```

`item_variant` is supposed to get value of product variant viewed or added to cart such as S,M,XL or 1 pack, 2 pack etc.
The problem is that when item is viewed - `item_variant` gets normal value but when variant on the product page is changed (URL is changed also with appended query parameter ,e.g ?variant=37281560494243) , `item_variant` is sent with the previous value same of *view_item* event.

At the same time I am observing native google ads *add_to_cart* event in dataLayer and `item_variant` there gets changed value:

```
 eventModel: {
    ecomm_prodid: ["shopify_US_5937481679011_37281560494243"],
    ecomm_totalvalue: 40,
    ecomm_pagetype: "cart",
    value: 40,
    currency: "USD",
    items: [
      {
        id: 5937481679011,
        name: "Stick - 2 pack",
        category: "Stick",
        price: "40",
        quantity: "1",
        variant: "2 pack"
      }
     ]
```

Tried to assign other variables as {{ product.selected_variant.title }} and {{ item.variant.title }}. Nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer on my own. In order to pass correct variant title or id of the item added to cart we need to add iteration on `product.variants` to the   `ecommerce` variable and modify with proper liquid variable `variant.title` or `variant.id`

```
{% if template contains 'product' %}
            dataLayer.push({
              'ecommerce': null
            });
            var ecommerce = {
                'items': [{
                    'item_id'        : {{product.id | json}},                 
                    {% for variant in product.variants %}
                    'item_variant'    : {{variant.title | json}},
                     {% endfor %}               
                    'item_name'      : {{product.title | json}},
                    'price'           : {{product.price | divided_by: 100.0 | json}},
                    'item_brand'      : {{product.vendor | json}},
                    'item_category'   : {{product.type | json}},
                    'item_list_name'  : {{collection.title | json}},
                    'description'     : {{product.description | strip_newlines | strip_html | json}},
                    'imageURL'        : 'https:{{product.featured_image.src|img_url:'grande'}}', 
                    'productURL'      : '{{product.url}}'
                }]
            };              
            $(__DL__.cartTriggers).click(function(){
                   dataLayer.push({                    
                    'event'    : 'add_to_cart',
                    ecommerce
                });                  
            });              
        {% endif %}
```